# nginx reverse proxy spring security authentication GET instead of POST

Tags: tomcat, nginx, centos7

Im having trouble properly setting up Nginx as a reverse proxy for a tomcat hosted application, which uses spring security for authentication.
The spring authentication module on the application is rejecting  logins with

`2018-11-06 19:30:01 DEBUG http-nio-8443-exec-398 @ 1951e0f24163 [OneTimePasswordAuthenticationFilter] - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Authentication method not supported: GET`

The Nginx logs appear to be sending the authentication as GET requests, and I dont understand why, but I can see the failure :

```
192.168.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:18:08:56 +0000] "POST /rear/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 161 "https://nginx_server/remote_rear/login/auth?login_error=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:18:08:56 +0000] "GET /remote_rear/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://nginx_server/remote_rear/login/auth?login_error=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36" "-"
192.168.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:18:08:56 +0000] "GET /rear/login/authfail;jsessionid=81EF0C82C98FC746D7641E6845E105D7?login_error=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 161 "https://nginx_server/remote_rear/login/auth?login_error=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

My current proxy configuration, based on what I was able to google and test is:

```
server {
   listen 443 default_server ssl;
        location /remote_rear {
            proxy_set_header  Host  $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO '$https';
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass      https://real_server:8443/rear;
            #proxy_redirect     https://real_server:8443/rear /rear;
            proxy_redirect     http://$host https://$host;
        }
        location /rear {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO '$https';
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            rewrite ^/rear/(.*)$ /remote_rear/$1 redirect;
        }
}
```

I am really stumped as to why the j_spring_security_check URL is being sent as GET instead of POST, and I would really appreciate someone explaining what I am doing wrong, and how I can fix it.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What does your browser network log tell? Does it POST or GET only? You'd add more Tomcat log, Spring configuration and maybe the login Form HTML

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have access to the tomcat log or spring configuration, nor would I be able to recognize it if I saw it. What I do know is, when using it without a proxy, presents a dialog box after login, for entering an OTP value. This isnt seen when proxying.